# Facebook Version 2.0 sending any kind of invitation to friends possibilities? And getting friend list

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My company is working on a project where we mainly need two-three things from facebook get back the list of friends who are using our application, send any kind of invitation to other friends and maybe post on user wall.

What are our possibilities since I see that version 2.0 is very limited compared to 1.0 I just want to confirm this with someone who has recently did more research on this.

How I see Graph API( /me/friends) only returns the list of friends who are using the application and gave permission for **user_friends**. And pretty much no way of getting full firend list of a user.

Second sending notifcations or any kind of message to new users or is there possibility to share it on IOS/Android. After some research how I see chat,messaging is depricated only https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog is available and

`invitable_friends` only available for games.

Is there anything that we might be missing could anyone give us some advice what is possible since there are a lot of suggestions on the internet on this but not all are up to date.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share - that is how you share stuff. you don´t need to invite users, and you should never auto-send something to a user - which is not possible anyway, at least not on android/ios apps, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct [Friends list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends) will only return app using friends . And `invitable_friends` is only for gaming app. I was hoping that something would change in Graph API 2.1 but they have become more strict .

Rest API which was  depricated is now stopped. Here are changes in [Graph API verision 2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) as compared to version 2.0

This is the way facebook wants it, so appereantly there is no way to get friends list or to send invites to **Non App using friends**

You can see the future [migrations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations) and [Platform version details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions) indicating Facebook is in no mood to make any changes regarding this in near future